# RxJava in a Service

Tags: android, service, notifications, rx-java, retrofit2

In my app to make network calls I use the `RxJava 1.1.6` and `Retrofit 2.1.0`. I need to implement offline mode - sync all data in my app with the data on the back-end. I tried to use Service + RxJava  but I faced with some problem - I wanted to send some notifications from the my RxJava chain but it looks like I can't do that. It seems that this chain executes in the different thread, not in that one that my Service works. But I didn't change the thread for RxJava chain.) Below I attached the code that I run.

```
protected void handleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "################ handleIntent ");
    if (isStarted) {
      return;
    }

    final ArrayList<Integer> languageKeys = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(LANGUAGES_KEY);
    final ArrayList<Integer> currencyKeys = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(CURRENCY_KEY);

    Log.d(TAG, "handleIntent: ");
    showStartLoadingNotifications(NOTIFICATION_ID, "Test: Data sync started"); //this one works fine
   Observable.just(null)
      .flatMap(o -> networkUtils.networkAvailable())
      .filter(isRequestAllowed -> isRequestAllowed)
      .flatMap(isRequestAllowed -> {
        if (isRequestAllowed) {
          showStartLoadingNotifications(NOTIFICATION_ID, "Data sync started"); //this one doesn't work
        } else {
          stopSelf();
          hideNotification(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
        return just(isRequestAllowed);
      })
      .doOnNext(o -> isStarted = true)
      .doOnNext(o -> {
        DaoMaster.dropAllTables(daoSession.getDatabase(), true);
        DaoMaster.createAllTables(daoSession.getDatabase(), true);
      })
      .concat(from(prepareRequests(languageKeys, currencyKeys)))
      .subscribe(loadAllResponse -> {
        },
        throwable -> {
          Log.d(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
          isStarted = false;
        }, () -> {
          isStarted = false;
          stopSelf();
        });
    Log.d(TAG, "##############  handleIntent: finished");
  }
```

The `prepareRequests(languageKeys, currencyKeys)` method returns the `List<Observable<LoadAllResponse>>`.
All works fine service works as expected: data is downloading and storing in the DB but I cannot send the notification to the system.

Has someone faced with a similar issue? Also does someone know in what thread it is run and how to change the thread for this chain to get ability to send notifications?

Comment: show the code for `showStartLoadingNotifications`? What is your target and compile SDK?

Comment: `Intent stopSelf = new Intent(this, LoadAllService.class);
    stopSelf.setAction(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1243, stopSelf, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentText(text)
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cava_logo)
      .setOngoing(true)
      .setProgress(1, 0, true)
      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)`

Comment: `.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Stop", pendingIntent)
      .build();
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);`

Comment: please edit the question, the code is unreadable in comments

Comment: @LordRaydenMK target and compile sdk are 25

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification):

Required notification contents
A Notification object must contain the following:

- A small icon, set by setSmallIcon().
- A title, set by setContentTitle().
- Detail text, set by setContentText().

On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, a valid notification channel ID, set by setChannelId() or provided in the NotificationCompat.Builder constructor when creating a channel.

You are missing `setContentTitle()`

Comment: I appreciate that, but as I highlighted  in the source code with `//` that it shows notification that was sent outside the RxJava chain, but it do not send the notification from the chain. And I use the android 7.1.1 to test that.

Comment: @Maxim are you sure the method is called from within the chain?

Comment: I'm sure, the chain is executing by the end - I receive all data that I expect also the methods onNext and onComplete are called.

Comment: @Maxim maybe add a log inside `showStartLoadingNotifications` to make sure it's executed. Notification should work from a worker thread.

Comment: Man, you was right, it wasn't called, thank you for the help, I guess I need to take a break and drink a cup of coffee. But anyway I'd like to know on what thread RxJava runs inside the Service, because I didn't modified the thread for chain but it makes call to the network and do not freeze the app.

Comment: @Maxim Assuming it's an `IntentService` RxJava should run on the thread the service is running unless there is `subscribeOn`/`observeOn` somewhere in the chain. You can check it out by calling `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Comment: This is the simple Service not the IntentService, if I run this chain inside the onHandleIntent in the IntentService, it(IntentService) starts (RxJava)request and calls onDestroy(). But RxJava keeps working in the background - that's what I wonder on what thread it works)